# Inhomogeneous Bernoulli Equation

Tags: differential-equations

Does anybody suggest how to face the inhomogeneous Bernoulli differential equation
$y'+P(x)y=Q(x)y^n+f(x)$
for the simple case $f=const.$ and for the generic case.
I would like to know about techniques of approximation, bounds, asymptotic limit, numerical techniques etc.
Thank you
Roberto

Comment: I fear you should move your question to http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume your $f(t)$ should be $f(x)$.  This is Chini's equation.  See e.g. 
http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=odeadvisor/Chini

Comment: Thank you,
of course $f(t)$ is $f(x)$.
Thanks for the answer.
Roberto

Answer (score -2):

Solution:
let u=y^(1-n)
du/dx = (1-n) y^(-n) dy/dx
      = (1-n) y^(-n) [
-Py+Qy^n+f]
  =-(1-n) Pu +(1-n)Q +(1-n)f u^(n/n-1)

Separation of variables
[1/(1-n)]Int[du/ { f u^(n/n-1)+Pu-Q}]= Int[dx]= x+ C
Factor out the division and integrates the LHS.
We get F(u,x)=0
then transform into F(y,x)=0.

For n=2, it is very easy to solve. You can try it.

Comment: You can't separate the variables since $P,~Q,~f$ depend on $x$. Have *you* tried it? In general these equations are not solvable by quadrature when $PQf\neq0$.

Comment: Yes, it can be done for the cases that PQf are constants. If they are functions of x, cannot solved by separation. Thks a lot for your reminding. I walked too quickly in simplified form.

Comment: When PQf are constants and n=2, LHS becomes (1/1-n) (1/f)(1/(u1-u2) ln |(u-u1)/(u-u2)|= x+C where u1 and u2 are two roots of u^2 +P/f u - Q/f =0.

Comment: When n=2, PQf depend on x. This is Ricatti's Eq. It can also be transformed to 2nd-order linear ODE. Seehttps://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation

Comment: Well, yes, *I* know that (and a lot of other people here also do…) so that referring to Wikipedia is besides the point. Just check your maths before posting, please. And also, please use LaTeX typesetting…